# Are $\operatorname{Spec}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x]$ and $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ homeomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the algebraic closure of the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}\cup\{(p): p\text{ is prime}\}$ and the  closed points of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ is $(p)$. The closure of $\{0\}$ is $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$.

And I have proved that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is countable. But I am not sure about how does  $\operatorname{Spec}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x]$ look like. I was thinking if I could find a bijection of closed point and non-closed point of these two sets, then I can say they are homeomorphic in Zariski topology. Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prime ideals of $\overline{\Bbb Q}[x]$ are $\{0\}$ and $(x-a)$
for $a\in\overline{\Bbb Q}$. So the spectrum consists of countably infinitely many
closed points and one dense point, just as the spectrum of $\Bbb Z$ has.
These spectra are therefore homeomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really helped.